# Needed help in drawing CMOS design and euler path p-tree ,n-tree for boolean function

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, vlsi

I have the expression \$Z=(A(D+E)+(BC))'\$, I'm trying to draw CMOS logic but I guess I've gone wrong somewhere.
I'm unable to draw Euler path for this diagram

[image: edited image]

Comment: does your lecture not demand a maximum "stackable" height of FETs? I mean, there's nothing wrong in general with having 4 FETs in series, but it requires a bit of voltage differential...

Comment: Well what you have currently on the top is (B'+C')(A'+D'E') and on bottom you have (ABC(D+E))'. These are supposed to be equal to your equation and complementary.

Comment: I noticed your edit, it looks like you followed the advice of Shashank V M. Do you still have an issue with the new circuit?

Comment: Yes I'm unable to draw Euler path for node numbered 2&3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is wrong. In pull-down network, series combination of B and C should be in parallel with {A, D, E} network since it is an OR function. Pull-up network is correct. The {A, D, E} network is correct in the pull-down network.

Pull-down network and pull-up networks have to be **duals** of each other.